# java:replacing " with \"

Tags: java, string

How can I escape the double quotes in a string? 
For eg,

```
input: "Nobody"
output:  \"Nobody\"
```

I tried sth like this,which is not working:

```
String name = "Nobody";
name.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Bear in mind that in `String name = "Nobody"` the double quotes are not actually part of the string, they're merely delimiters.

Comment: Sorry, My Apologies: string is like this: String name = ""Nobody"";

Comment: That would not be correct syntax, I suspect you mean `String name = "\"Nobody\"";`, which results in the output `"Nobody"`.

Answer (score 6):

Because your string "Nobody" doesn't have any double quotes in it!

```
    String name = "Nobo\"dy";
    name = name.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");

    System.out.println(name);
```

1. Your string didn't have double quotes
2. You weren't reassigning name (remember that strings are immutable in Java)
3. Your regex wasn't exactly correct.

Besides, you don't need a RegEx for such a simple replacement.

Just try

```
    name = name.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: Sorry, My Apologies: string is like this: String name = ""Nobody"";

Answer (score 5):

adarshr is right but also, notice that you are ignoring the returned string, do it like this:

```
String name = "Nobody";
name = name.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

Strings in java are imutable

*Edit:* Since I wrote that, adarshr has changed his answer to the better (if anyone wonder why I wrote that)

Answer (score 0):

name.replaceAll(...) does not change name - it returns the string so you need to write:

```
name = name.replaceAll(...)
```

[JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

besides that your string doesn't contain a "

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.bradino.com/javascript/string-replace/ as it gives tips on replacing all.

You can do just one with:

var name = '"Nobody"';
name = name.replace("\"", "\\"");

Regards

AJ